# Locked out of all accounts after 3 failed logins to user account

Tags: login, password

I fired up my Ubuntu VM on VirtualBox after several weeks of non-usage.  I have an administrator account and a non-administrator account.  I have stored the administrator password in a text file on the host OS (Windows 10).  I did not store the password for the non-administrator account because it was "so easy to remember" (so I thought at the time) and because if I ever did forget it, I could always log into the administrator account to reset the password for the non-administrator account.

Shockingly, I forgot the non-administrator account password.  I failed three times to log in.  This  seemed to lock me out in the sense that I am no longer presented with a password prompt when I select the non-administrator account.  I then resorted to my clever plan of logging into the administrator account to reset the password for the non-administrator account.  Unfortunately, I don't get a password prompt for that either.

**Is it normal for Ubuntu to lock out *all* accounts because of 3 failed logins for one account?**

That seems odd, but my context for thinking this is ye olde SUN SPARC terminals for undergraduates of yesterdecade.  They ran X-Windows over a LAN.  Just because one student failed to login, it doesn't mean that the next student to use the terminal should be locked out.  Times have changed, of course.

I am still not getting password prompts for administrator and non-administrator accounts after 20 minutes, even though I have not made another attempt to log in.

**P.S.** The problem went away after rebooting Ubuntu.  But it still seems odd.  Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I've never been locked out of Ubuntu (Kubuntu or MATE) despite at least once taking five tries to figure out my caplock was on or numlock wasn't.  Then again, I don't run in a VM, I'm on bare metal; Ubuntu is my daily driver.

Comment: @Zeiss Kon: Would you know if you are using Ubuntu out-of-the (ISO) box?  I'm running on complete defaults.  It doesn't seem like a VirtualBox thing.  The behaviour seems to be completely contained within the Ubuntu VM.

Comment: I'm currently running Kubuntu 20.04 with the default setup to require login -- but no "admin" or "root" account, as recommended for Ubuntu since at least 16.04.  I've used Kubuntu 14.04, MATE 16.04, and Kubuntu 20.04 as my daily driver for about eight years, always with login, and with root password set through 16.04.  I installed directly from a downloaded ISO in each case (too much installed software to depend on the upgrade process, which basically just disables all of those repos/PPAs).

Comment: I'm relatively new to Ubuntu, but I suspect that the defaults for Kubuntu might be different than for Ubuntu (20.04.3 LTS).

Comment: Well, it's a different greeter and desktop environment, so of course things are different.  MATE, on the other hand (which I have run with a root account) is very similar to Ubuntu 14 with Gnome, since MATE is a branch of Gnome 2 (Ubuntu went to Gnome 3).